# Python socket gives [WinError 10057] with Ethernet cable connection

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I'm trying to simulate a network that continuously (at least 24h) exchange data, therefore I connected two Laptops (OS Windows) through Ethernet cable and give each Ethernet port a static IP address (192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2). The cable are connected with a switch and on the switch there is a port mirroring the data on Raspi because with Wireshark I would like to analyse the traffic and do some tests.

I found the code to simulate server and client [here](https://github.com/realpython/materials/tree/master/python-sockets-tutorial) and I'm using multiconn-client.py and multiconn-server.py. If I test the code on localhost it does work fine but if I change the host with the static IP address of the machine simulating the server than I get WinError 10060.
I read many other similar topics, but since my development environment is peculiar no solution was working for me.

Maybe it is worth to mention that the laptops are also connected to wifi, at the beginning I thought this was the problem, but when I turned the wifi off I had the same issue.

EDIT:

This is the Traceback for client.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-7-1885b422d65a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:.../MultiConnectionClient.py', wdir='C.../pyscript')

  File "C:...Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:...Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:.../MultiConnectionClient.py", line 68, in <module>
    service_connection(key, mask)

  File "C:.../MultiConnectionClient.py", line 49, in service_connection
    sent = sock.sendall(data.outb)  # Send message

OSError: [WinError 10057] Eine Anforderung zum Senden oder Empfangen von Daten wurde verhindert, da der Socket nicht verbunden ist und (beim Senden über einen Datagrammsocket mit einem sendto-Aufruf) keine Adresse angegeben wurde
```

Concerning the server I tried some debugging with TCPView and although the server seems to start and the code is executed I find no trace of it on TCPView.

Comment: I think you should include the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my windows defender firewall. I had to disable it for "Guest or public networks" I guess somehow the Ethernet cable connection was classified as public network.